# How to copy properties from a parent project in gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to share one messages.properties (of each language) among multiple subprojects in gradle, one of which is a war and the rest are jars. My directory structure looks like this:

```
Top Level Project
  + Project War/
  + Project Jar/
  + Project Jar/
  ...
  + common/resources/properties files
  + build.gradle
```

I am trying to do something like this in the main project level build.gradle (which doesn't look to be working for me):

```
task copyProperties(type: Copy) {
   description = 'Copies the messages.properties to individual projects.'
   from relativePath('./common/resources')
   into output.resourceDir
   include '*.properties'
}
```

I'm calling this from a subproject's compileJava.dependsOn and I don't see any errors, but the copy doesn't happen.

Comment: What gradle output are you getting? Is the copyProperties task being called for each subproject or just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject a copy task like this into each sub-project. Instead of specifying the 'from' as a relative path, base it on $rootDir.

Each copy task should then be called as needed when building each sub-project.

Comment: Thanks!  I also changed into to be "into (sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)" and that works!